# How can you capture window exit button with Rust?

Tags: windows, events, rust

I just want to capture the event triggered by exiting the application via the X button of the window. I tried searching but to no avail. Is there any built-in code for this?

Comment: We're going to need more than this to help you. In particular, are you using any window/GUI library such as GTK or otherwise? This is crucially important, as this is what will mediate the close event.

Comment: For transparency, this question was also [posted in Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/d77yk4/how_can_you_capture_window_exit_button_on_windows/).

Comment: "*Is there any built-in code for this?*" -> No. This is an interaction with the platform dependent windowing-system. Your question is a bit too open ended and broad for SO. Asking on Reddit (as you already did) or on users.rust-lang.org would be a better idea. You can ask again here when you have a more specific question. Also, it's unclear if you're only asking about Microsoft Windows or about windows in general.